# How to tell ffmpeg to skip the last NAL unit?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg and trying to use it to record a streaming video (e.g. recording YouTube streams). However, I guess sometimes due to network issues, the last NAL unit is corrupted and when I want to concat multiple videos together, the error below occurs and the process exited.

```
[NULL @ 0x558551957ec0] Invalid NAL unit size (41974 > 39166).bitrate=12309.0kbits/s speed=21.5x
[NULL @ 0x558551957ec0] missing picture in access unit with size 39182
[concat @ 0x55855194c700] h264_mp4toannexb filter failed to receive output packet
../filelist.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way to tell ffmpeg to skip the last NAL unit (or skip any invalid NAL unit) without re-encoding the entire video? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try this on the input `-fflags +discardcorrupt` ?

Comment: @thekamilz Yes, I tried, but No it doesn't work...